# ERROR: "Module not found: Can't resolve" when importing custom component, but the path is 100% correct?

Tags: error, component, not-found, react, scandipwa

I'm getting this error trying to import a custom component, but my path is correct?

> Failed to compile. ./src/component/Footer/Footer.component.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve
> '/scandipwa/src/component/FooterLinks'
> in
>  '/scandipwa/src/component/Footer'

But the path is correct?

Here's a view of my file structure and my imports - "FooterLogo" and "FooterTagline" are working fine, just not "FooterLinks" and they are all in the same path.

[image]

I've also added the path using autocomplete in VS Code. It is 100% correct, but the error persists?

What could be causing this?

Comment: I didn't figure out what actually caused the issue, but I rebooted VS code and it went away.